# GTest linking error: undefined reference to 'foo::function'

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, googletest, undefined-reference

I want to use GTest and got the example to work. Now I want to test my own code, but I get a linking problem.

I've search on stackoverflow, and found a similar problem but the answers didn't help me to fix my problem.

My files are:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=gnu++11")

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
file(GLOB files
    Datahandler.h 
    Datahandler.cpp 
    )

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest and pthread library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp ${files} )
target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

**tests.cpp**

```
#include "DataHandler.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(checkFilled, All){
    DataHandler handler("loc", "prot", 1);
    handler.filledElement[1] = 1;
    ASSERT_EQ(1, handler.checkFilled(1));
    ASSERT_EQ(0, handler.checkFilled(2));
    ASSERT_EQ(1, handler.checkFilled(8));
    ASSERT_EQ(0, handler.checkFilled(9));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/tests.cpp.o: In function `checkFilled_All_Test::TestBody()':
tests.cpp:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `DataHandler::DataHandler(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char)'
tests.cpp:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `DataHandler::checkFilled(unsigned char)'
tests.cpp:(.text+0x271): undefined reference to `DataHandler::checkFilled(unsigned char)'
tests.cpp:(.text+0x382): undefined reference to `DataHandler::checkFilled(unsigned char)'
tests.cpp:(.text+0x48d): undefined reference to `DataHandler::checkFilled(unsigned char)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target 'runTests' failed
make[2]: *** [runTests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/runTests.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm almost certain it has something to do with include or link problem, but I cant find the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several points in your CMake project:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=gnu++11")
```

When using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, it is a good practice to not erase previous value:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
```

By default, the value is empty, so that shouldn't change anything here. Anyway, to require C++11, you may consider instead `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

Next:

```
file(GLOB files
    Datahandler.h 
    Datahandler.cpp 
    )
```

If you use `GLOB`, you should pass file patterns, not file paths. Anyway, from the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html):

> We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.

Consider `set` instead:

```
set(files
    Datahandler.h 
    Datahandler.cpp 
    )
```

Next:

```
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#...

target_link_libraries(runTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

Instead of old-fashioned `${GTEST_LIBRARIES}`, you may consider [imported targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets):

```
target_link_libraries(runTests GTest::Main)
```

`GTest::Main` will handle include directories through the imported target, so you don't need to call `include_directories`. Moreover, it will add a dependency to a thread library, so I am pretty sure you can remove `pthread` (to be tested). Finally, `GTest::Main` includes a basic implementation of the main function which does exactly what you did, so you can remove yours.

Note that you will need to upgrade the minimum required version of CMake to make imported targets fully availables:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
```

---

So your CMake project in 2016 should look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(files
    Datahandler.h 
    Datahandler.cpp 
    )

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

# Link runTests with what we want to test and the GTest library
add_executable(runTests tests.cpp ${files})

target_link_libraries(runTests GTest::Main)
```

And `test.cpp`:

```
#include "DataHandler.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(checkFilled, All){
    DataHandler handler("loc", "prot", 1);
    handler.filledElement[1] = 1;
    ASSERT_EQ(1, handler.checkFilled(1));
    ASSERT_EQ(0, handler.checkFilled(2));
    ASSERT_EQ(1, handler.checkFilled(8));
    ASSERT_EQ(0, handler.checkFilled(9));
}
```

Comment: one of the greatest answers of all time